# Pandas get type using value counts

Tags: python, pandas

```
# col is a series
t = col.apply(type).value_counts()
t_count = zip(t.index, t)
```

I have a result of `t.index` being `<type 'int'>`. How do i determine that this type is int. Basically i would like something like this

```
<type 'int'> == type(int) #It is returning false currently but i would like it to return true without converting it to a str and processing it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare with `int`:

```
col =  pd.Series([1,2,'a','d','d',1.5,7.8])
t = col.apply(type).value_counts() 
print (t)
<class 'str'>      3
<class 'float'>    2
<class 'int'>      2
dtype: int64

print (t.index == int)
[False False  True]

print (t[t.index == int])
<class 'int'>    2
dtype: int64
```

Also is possible compare `Series`:

```
print (col.apply(type) == int)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool

print (col[col.apply(type) == int])
0    1
1    2
dtype: object
```